# Dynamic Android and iPhone Application Festival Event Application

Tags: android, iphone, cross-platform, dynamic-data

Is there a way to build and Android and iPhone application that automatically updates its content.

For Example: the user has download the application and we have all of our data on there and what not but then we get another entertainer that is coming to the festival and we want to list them in the app. Do I have to "Publish" an update for the users to download of can all that information be dynamic and automatically retrieved from a server every time the person has internet.

Does that makes sense to anyone, I hope it does.

Comment: Either make use of a push server ( a lot of sample code on the web available ) or make the application fetch every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

How you achieve it is to broad a topic without some more information about your specific situation. In general what you'll be looking to do is host your content online somewhere and have your application pull the most recent version when it begins.

There are many possible ways you could store your data online XML, JSON, RSS are a few that are pretty common. Which you'd want to use depends on exactly what the data you are sharing is.

Comment: Thank you and to give some information on what I am wanting to do.

Comment: I am building a application for a festival, I can make a static application just fine, but what the application needs to pull from the internet is information on entertainers and events happening at the Festival. Say we have 3 entertainers when I launch the application, then 2 weeks later we now have 4 entertainer. Instead of issuing an update I want to do a Push Notification and then when they go to the app they have a new entertainer in the menu under entertainers they can click the artists name and get information about them and even view a youtube video